# What is standard deviation, variance and R square in Linear Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am learning regression and classification the past week as a part of my machine learning class. So, I have understood what is linear regression and how the coefficient error values are calculated for the equation:

y = b0 + b1X+ e

But what exactly does R^Square, variance and standard deviation mean for a Predicted model?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Did they teach about these concepts ($R^2$ etc.) in the class? Or you want us to explain them from scratch?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I have a basic understanding about $r^2$ (like, it explains the proportion of variance of dependent variable ) but I would be more than thankful if you can help me down understand better.